# What is the equivalent of exports.someFunction in ES6?

Tags: node.js, express

I can't seem to figure out how to run this following code. What is the equivalent of this code in ES6?

```
\\controller.js
exports.someFunction = [middleware1, middleware2, (req, res) => {...}]

\\app.js
const controller = require("./controllers/controller");
app.use('/', controller.someFunction)
```

I know each function can be exported, but I want to keep the `controller.someFunction` syntax as I think it is easier to read.

Comment: `import * as controller from "path/to/module"` would give you every named (i.e. non-`default`) `export` in an object named `controller`, if that's what you mean? (FWIW I think separating "router" and "controller", both part of the transport layer, into two files just encourages putting too much stuff in the controller and exposes a boundary you _shouldn't_ be testing at).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe wrote, you can use `import * from ...` syntax

```
//controller.js
export const someFunction = [middleware1, middleware2, (req, res) => {...}] //??
// or
export function someFunction () {
 //...
}

//app.js
import * as controller from "./controllers/controller"
app.use('/', controller.someFunction)
```